# WP_Query do not include posts with a certain value in a custom field -

Tags: wp-query

I am trying to grab the 5 most recent posts and have it exclude posts in an array that is already defined ($exclude), sticky posts and any posts that are checked off as a featured post (i.e. with the custom field "my_featured_post" set to 1)

I tried:

```
$args = array('post__not_in' => $exclude,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'meta_query'=> array(
        array(
        'key'=>'my_featured_post',
        'value'=>'1',
        'compare'=>'!='
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

and :

```
$args = array('post__not_in' => $exclude,
                      'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
                      'paged'=>1,
          'posts_per_page' => 5,
          'meta_key'=>'my_featured_post',
          'meta_value'=>'1',
          'meta_compare'=>"!="

                    );
```

Neither returned any posts. If i remove the references to meta in either query, it returns a mix of posts set as "my_featured_posts" and not set as such.

Am I going about this wrong?

Thanks,
gS

Answer (score 0):

Try adding the type parameter:

```
$args = array('post__not_in' => $exclude,
    'ignore_sticky_posts' => 1,
    'posts_per_page' => 5,
    'meta_query'=> array(
        array(
        'key'=>'my_featured_post',
        'value'=> 1,
        'type' => 'numeric', // assuming your custom_value is an int, not a string.
        'compare'=>'!='
        )
    )
);
$query = new WP_Query($args);
```

Comment: This did not work - it returns posts with my_featured_post set to 1 and those without it set at all...

Comment: I'd missed the quotes around 'numeric', fixed now. Was that it?

Comment: Huh? Can you run that by me again?

Comment: Nevermind last comment. No dice :\ -- I was thinking maybe i have the wrong key - but when I set compare to just "=" I get the same exact results instead of a subset of just featured posts...